# Best Method: Parsing CSV file and Passing back to front end using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have a CSV file that is uplaoded to my server where a PHP script will parse and return output to JavaScript via AJAX.

The CSV file is made up of two rows. First row contains the column names and the second row contains the data. I am trying to write a script that will parse it in a form that will be usable by Javascript to generate text fields and labels populated with this data. The current method that I have is this:

```
if ( $_FILES['parameter_file']['tmp_name'] ) {

    $paramfile = fopen($_FILES['parameter_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    $header = fgets($paramfile);
    $temp = explode(',', str_replace('"', '', rtrim(ltrim($header))));

    $userdata = fgets($paramfile);
    $temp2 = explode(',', str_replace('"', '', rtrim(ltrim($userdata))));

    for ($k = 0; $k <= sizeof($temp) - 1; $k++) {
        $userparam[strtolower($temp[$k])] = $temp2[$k];
    }

    fclose($paramfile);
}
```

I can see loads of room for general improvement, feel free to point them out. But the main question is would a json_encode be all I need. Anything more efficient? A better idea?

Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Lukáš Lalinský](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60950/lukas-lalinsky) wrote in his comment to [csl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534396/best-method-parsing-csv-file-and-passing-back-to-front-end-using-ajax/1534428#1534428) [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is your friend (by the way [`str_getcsv()`](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) is not available prior to PHP 5.3).

The code should be a simple as (error-handling is left to the OP):

```
$headers   = null;
$rowNum    = 0;
$tableData = array();
$handle    = fopen($_FILES['parameter_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    if ($rowNum == 0) {
        // parsing the CSV header
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            $headers[] = $d;
        }
    } else {
        // parsing the data rows
        $rowData = array();
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            $rowData[] = $d;
        }
        $tableData[] = array_combine($headers, $rowData)
    }
    $rowNum++;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Given a CSV file of:

```
id,name,value
1,first,value1
2,second,value2
3,third,value3
```

this will give you a `headers`-array with

```
array(
    0 => 'id',
    1 => 'name',
    2 => 'value'
)
```

and a `$tableData`-array with

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'id'    => '1',
        'name'  => 'first',
        'value' => 'value1'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id'    => '2',
        'name'  => 'second',
        'value' => 'value2'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id'    => '3',
        'name'  => 'third',
        'value' => 'value3'
    )
)
```

Adjust the code as needed...

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use [str_getcsv()](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) / [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and then [json_encode()](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  In between, you can always shuffle the data to make the outputted JSON look as you want.

In general, it's better to use the library functions if they are available.

Comment: Since he is parsing a physical file, `fgetcsv` might be a better choice.